# clearTimeout not working React Natve

Tags: react-native, settimeout, keyboard-events

I have an app that needs to stay on all the time. To stop the ipad from shutting down/sleeping after 5 hours of inactivity I have the home screen reloading every 4 hours. But I don't want it to refresh if a user is using the keyboard. I have the app refreshing but i can not stop the timer on my keyboardDidShow listener. Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.keyboardDidShowListener = 
   Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
 this.keyboardDidHideListener = 
   Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
 this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(()=>{
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
 },30000);
}

_keyboardDidShow () {
 console.log("Keyboard Shown")
 if (this.timeoutHandle) {
  clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle);
  this.timeoutHandle = 0;
 }
};

componentWillUnmount(){
 this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
 this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
 clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle);
}

_keyboardDidHide () {
console.log('Keyboard Hidden');
}
```

I have tried a bunch of different ways, but am unable to clear the timer on keyboardDidShow. Please help if you can.

Comment: You need to bind `this` to the event listeners, or use a fat arrow function when referring to the listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are getting executed in the wrong context.

These lines:

```
 this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
 this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
```

need to change to this:

```
 this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
 this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this));
```

Comment: Quickest answer in history of stackoverflow? Dude thank you so much, was driving me nuts.